# What can I do to reduce my click event codes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, object, onclick

I am having trouble fitting my click events together, since they seem like the could be condensed, I am still not able to figure out how to organize it properly

my JS

```
 $(".container").hide();

  $("#welcome").show();
  //for phone add an on click event for .dropdown, and pust display:show for .dropdown-content
  $(".dropdown").click(function() {
    $(".dropdown-content").toggle();
  });

  // add click event for .dropdown-content
  //click for #wel
  $("#wel").click(function() {
    $(".container").hide();
    show: $("#welcome").show();
  });
  // if #me clicked hide: $(".container").hide();, main page we'll implement later, and show: $("#aboutMe").show();
  $("#me").click(function() {
    $(".container").hide();
    show: $("#aboutMe").show();
  });
  // else if #port clicked hide: $(".container").hide();, main page we'll implement later, and show: $("#portfolio").show();
  $("#port").click(function() {
    $(".container").hide();
    show: $("#portfolio").show();
  });
  //else if youtube clicked
  $("#yubby").click(function() {
    $(".container").hide();
    show: $("#tubez").show();
  });
  // else if #contact clicked hide: $(".container").hide();, main page we'll implement later, and show: $("#contact").show();
  $("#contact").click(function() {
    $(".container").hide();
    show: $("#cont").show();
  });
```

my html

```
 <nav class="dropdown">
            <p class="animated pulse" id="pimp"> Juan Alberto Pimentel JR
            </p>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                <p class="dropAns" id="wel">Welcome</p>
                <p class="dropAns" id="me">About Me</p>
                <p class="dropAns" id="port">Portfolio</p>
                <p class="dropAns" id="yubby">Youtube</p>
                <p class="dropAns" id="contact">Contact</p>
            </div>
        </nav>
<br>
<div class="container" id="welcome"></div>
<br>
<div class="container" id="aboutMe"></div>
<br>
<div class="container" id="portfolio"></div>
<br>
<div class="container" id="tubez"></div>
<br>
<div class="container" id="cont"></div>
```

Everytime I make a selection on my drowndown, I want it to show the specific container for that selection without having all these lines of code on my js

Comment: I suggest [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/), have a single handler and a map between ids of the clicked elements and the id of the element to show. Writing a full answer is outside the scope of SO. You have to try something and then we can tell you any problems with it if you can't get it to work.

Comment: Investigate [Event Delegation](https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate)

Comment: I'm not sure how event delegation is relevant here. Would you mind clarifying?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend giving each menu item a [data attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes).
Then use the data attribute of the clicked item to select the id of the desired container.

However, since `.dropAns` elements are descendants of `.dropdown`, clicking on `.dropAns` means you're also clicking on `.dropdown`. But we don't want the dropdown to toggle every time you click on a menu item. To prevent this, I've added [`stopPropagation()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) to the handler on `.dropAns`. See [Event bubbling and capture](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#Event_bubbling_and_capture).

```js
// toggle the menu on click
$(".dropdown").on('click', function() {
  $(".dropdown-content").toggle();
});

// toggle content
$(".dropAns").on('click', function(e) {

  // prevent event from bubbling up to .dropdown
  e.stopPropagation();

  // get the data attribute from the clicked item
  var id = $(this).data('id');

  // hide all containers
  $(".container").hide();

  // show the appropriate container
  $('#' + id).show();

});
```

```css
#pimp {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: darkblue;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropAns {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  margin: 1em 0 0;
  padding: 1em;
  background-color: lightblue;
  display: none;
}

#welcome {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<nav class="dropdown">
  <p class="animated pulse" id="pimp">Juan Alberto Pimentel JR</p>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <p class="dropAns" data-id="welcome">Welcome</p>
    <p class="dropAns" data-id="aboutMe">About Me</p>
    <p class="dropAns" data-id="portfolio">Portfolio</p>
    <p class="dropAns" data-id="tubez">Youtube</p>
    <p class="dropAns" data-id="cont">Contact</p>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="container" id="welcome">Welcome!</div>
<div class="container" id="aboutMe">About Me!</div>
<div class="container" id="portfolio">Portfolio!</div>
<div class="container" id="tubez">YouTube!</div>
<div class="container" id="cont">Contact!</div>
```

Comment: For the record, this is another favorite approach of mine, but, instead of using `show()` and `hide()`, I tend set up and "active" class that is set to "display: block;" and default the sections to "display: none;".  Then I `removeClass()` "active" from all of the sections and `addClass()` it to the specific section that was tied to the clicked menu item.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way that I've found to manage the display of content sections like this is to put them inside a common container and then use CSS to control which child section is displayed inside the parent.

Looking at the below code, I first started by adding a parent `<div>` with an `id` of "contentSections":

```
<div id="contentSections">
    . . . 
</div>
```

After that, I set the default style of each of the "container" `div` sections inside to be `display: none;`:

```
#contentSections .container {display: none;}
```

Now, with that set up, you can change the class on the parent (I added a class that matched the ID of the menu item that was clocked), and have CSS styles set up to show the content section that should be displayed, when the class is applied to the parent, using this pattern:

```
<p class="dropAns" id="MENU_ID">MENU_TEXT</p>

#contentSections.MENU_ID #SECTION_ID {display: block;}
```

Once each menu item/content section pairing has had CSS set up for it, it's just a question of updating the parent container with the appropriate class, when a menu item is clicked:

```
$(".dropAns").on('click', function(e) {
    $("#contentSections")[0].className = e.target.id;
});
```

**NOTE:** There are a number of other things that I would clean up (e.g., can be done without jQuery, could refactor the use of `id` and `class` attributes to declutter the code, etc.), but I didn't want to make too many changes, to the point that the code would become unfamiliar.  This should give you an idea of the concept behind it.

---

**UPDATE #1:** Forgot to default the "contentSections" to show the "Welcome" content.  Added a default "wel" class to the parent container to handle that.

```js
//for phone add an on click event for .dropdown, and pust display:show for .dropdown-content
$(".dropdown").click(function() {
  $(".dropdown-content").toggle();
});

// add click event for .dropdown-content
$(".dropAns").on('click', function(e) {
  $("#contentSections")[0].className = e.target.id;
});
```

```css
#contentSections .container {display: none;}
#contentSections.wel #welcome {display: block;}
#contentSections.me #aboutMe {display: block;}
#contentSections.port #portfolio {display: block;}
#contentSections.yubby #tubez {display: block;}
#contentSections.contact #cont {display: block;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="dropdown">
  <p class="animated pulse" id="pimp"> Juan Alberto Pimentel JR
  </p>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <p class="dropAns" id="wel">Welcome</p>
    <p class="dropAns" id="me">About Me</p>
    <p class="dropAns" id="port">Portfolio</p>
    <p class="dropAns" id="yubby">Youtube</p>
    <p class="dropAns" id="contact">Contact</p>
  </div>
</nav>
<div id="contentSections" class="wel">
  <div class="container" id="welcome">**Welcome content**</div>
  <div class="container" id="aboutMe">**About Me content**</div>
  <div class="container" id="portfolio">**Portfolio content**</div>
  <div class="container" id="tubez">**YouTube content**</div>
  <div class="container" id="cont">**Contact content**</div>
</div>
```